# What is the definition of a bounded sequence in a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, definition

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space where $X$ is some set and $d : X \times X \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a metric. And let $(x_n)$ be a sequence.

What is the definition of a bounded sequence in a metric space?

I would assume it's something of the form $\exists M , |x_n| \lt M$ for all $n$.  But $|x|$ might not have meaning depending on what metric space is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence is bounded if it is contained in a ball, so $\exists x^* \in X, M > 0$ such that $(x_n)\subseteq B_M(x^*)$. In some sense, you replace $|x_n| <M$ with $d(x^*,x_n) < M$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in an abstract metric space, without any assumed vector space structure, there may not be a special point identified as zero. So you won't be able to define an absolute value via $|x| := d(x,0)$, since there is no zero point in $X$. But zero isn't all that special anyway when determining the boundedness of subsets of $X$. You can center balls about any point in $X$. So, you can say the sequence $(x_{n})$ is bounded if it is contained in a ball centered about some point $x^{\ast}$ in $X$; that is, there is an $x^{\ast} \in X$ and a $M > 0$ such that $d(x_{n},x^{\ast}) < M$ for all $n$.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to observe that, if a sequence is bounded, and thus included in a ball around some $x^*$, then for any other point $z$ in that metric space, your sequence will also be included in a ball around $z$. This fact, which follows immediately from  the triangle inequality, reinforces what you wrote about "zero isn't all that special". Not only can you center balls around any point, but, whatever center you choose, you get the same bounded sequences.